# MediaComposition GetThumbnailAsync crashes

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I try to extract thumbnail from [StorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile) using Windows Media Editing API with the following code:

```
public async Task<IInputStream> GetThumbnailAsync(StorageFile file)
{
    var mediaClip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(file);

    var mediaComposition = new MediaComposition();
    mediaComposition.Clips.Add(mediaClip);

    return await mediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync(
        TimeSpan.Zero, 0, 0, VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame);
}
```

But I always get the error below.

*The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36B4)*

I have tried with different input file formats (avi / mp4 / mov) and smaller or bigger files with no luck.

I know I could extract the thumbnail of the file using [StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227212) API but this only works for the very first frame. And I need to be able to extract any arbitrary frame from the video file. So [MediaComposition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition) API seems to be able to deliver what I need.

Comment: Tested your code, I can't reproduce your problem. I can get the image from media file. So please post your more complete code.

Comment: This is all the code. There is nothing more, just input file.

Comment: I have uploaded my demo in [OneDrive](http://1drv.ms/1RrP4CV). It works in my side. Please have a check.

Comment: And it behaves exactly the same on my machine as it was reported, HRESULT: 0xC00D36B4. Maybe some system wide component is missing. The sample video I have used is [Sample Video](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4). It plays back nicely using built-in media player but I cannot extract frames.

Comment: Ok, it seems to run fine on Surface Pro 4 but not on my development machine. Need to find out why :(

Comment: Is there any reason why it could not work on virtualized environment?